# Informix OBDC error user validation

Tags: odbc, informix

I have a user called test in an informix database.

when I try to configure an OBDC connection with that user I get an error for invalid user called test@pcname.mynetwork.local.

why do I get @pcname.mynetwork.local after user name and how to avoid that?

Thank you

Comment: What version of Client SDK do you use? What system?

Comment: I'm using windowx xp odbc tool and IBM Informix OBDC setup utility version 3.70.TC5DE

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when I tried to choose "Database Name" with empty "User Id" and "Password" fields.

On the Connection tab of ODBC Driver Setup at first fill "User Id" and "Password". Then you can use drop down "Database Name".